# ReactJS - RTL Debug Component Logic

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I want to find out why my test not work as expected. So I want call `onSaved` callback when the action is `add` and not call it when the action is `edit`. But both of my test return `Number of calls: 1`. How is this possible? and how to figure it out? Thanks.

Form.jsx

```
function Form(action, onSaved){
  const handleSubmit() = {
     if (action === 'add') {
        createData(payload, {
           onSuccess: onSaved();
        });
     } else {
       updateData(payload);
     }
  }
  return (<form>...</form>)
}
```

Form.test.jsx

```
it('handle create', async () => {
   render(<Form action="add" onSaved={mockOnSaved} />);
   /.../
   fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button'));
   expect(mockOnSaved).toHaveBeenCalled(); //passed called once
})

it('handle update', async () => {
   render(<Form action="edit" onSaved={mockOnSaved} />);
   /.../
   fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button'));
   expect(mockOnSaved).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); //failed called once
})
```

Comment: Are you clearing your `mockOnSaved` before each test? You should clear it before each test with `mockOnSaved.mockClear();` if you dont do that the call count will not clear by default and in your case will continue to be 1 on the second test.

Answer (score 0):

You could clear all mocks in a `beforeEach` statement :

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});

it(...
```